# Change event firing without click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using the isotope plugin to create a function that allows me to place multiple select dropdowns. When the user has selected the dropdowns and when they click submit, it fires the event and rearranges the items.

The problem i am recieving is that the change event is firing and removing everything, but when i click submit, the right results are returned.

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var $container = $('.finalblock'),
      filters = {},
      selector;

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.finalchannel',
    layoutMode: 'none'
  });


  $('select').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
      $('#mainSubmission').click(function() {
        var group = $this.attr('data-filter-group');
        filters[ group ] = $this.find(':selected').attr('data-filter-value');
        var isoFilters = [];
        for ( var prop in filters ) {
          isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
        }
        var selector = isoFilters.join('');

        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
      });
  });
});
```

Iv been looking into the `bind()` function but that doesnt seem to be giving me the right thing (maybe cause i must be doing something wrong.

```
$('select').bind('initCheckboxes change', function() {
     // do some stuff including ajax work
}).trigger('initCheckboxes');
```

EDIT:
JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnzkv3v7/

Comment: What is initCheckboxes? bind and trigger should take an even name (like click, mouseenter and so on..). Also you can now embed javascript snippet with html if you need, or just provide a jsfiddle. It makes things easier for people willing to debug/help you.

Comment: differencias: `bind` event disable with `unbind`. `on` multiple event `.on('click, load, ...` another, one function `.click(...`

Comment: I can't find any difference yet, but I'm wondering, do you need the Submit button? You can just remove it and move the code from the click event to the select change event. Then it will work when the user selects from the dropdowns like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4cjqb9yc/

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your code, (on the website itself, not the jsfiddle):

The first select element has the id of `filters`

```
<select id="filters" data-filter-group="mainfilter">
```

but did you know that was stored as a variable in your js?

```
var $container = $('.finalblock'),
    filters = {},
    selector;
```

Since most of these elements are being pulled in by Isotope anyways, this could be the issue. The reason why this is a theory is because your second select element doesnt seem to be causing an issue. So change the first select id to something else and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you - just changed it to filters1 and it works perfectly. Thank you again!!